# can't open a shape file with pysal

Tags: python, spatial, pysal

i try to open a file using pysal wth that code:

```
import pysal
f=pysal.open()
```

and this the the response taht I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'pysal' has no attribute 'open'
```

What Im doing wrong?

Comment: the API changed with version 2 of pysal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pysal released breaking changes with version 2. `open` is no longer a top level import.

You can still open shapefiles with pysal, but you’ll need to first import `pysal.lib.io.open`

import pysal.lib.io.open
pysal.lib.io.open('Path/to/file.shp')